# How to animate and float text around like a cloud

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could not find anything on the web but i'm looking for a way to let text float around like a animated tag cloud.

The idea is simple, I want to animate text within a small area (10 or 20 px) random from left , top, right, bottom(not in this order ofcours).
The animation must be smooth and natural so not 5 px up then 10 px left etc. The text should hover/float arround.

The idea(not looking for the same thing, nor mouse controlled animations).
http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Minimal-jQuery-Based-3D-Ball-Tag-Cloud-cloudTag-js/

Comment: What have you tried? please show us

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the code of that example you shared?

It seems every tag has x,y,z coordinates and some animating functions move them with math functions **around a sphere**.

Maybe you can do something similar setting label on the text with a special name. Then, with a js function you can move that object only with x,y (and setting it with absolute position in css)

Give some more details or even attach some code if you've tried something already.

Comment: Im on my mobile and not near my PC for a week so I cant give an example on what I have tried, and my example is nothing more that 5 px up then 10 px right etc, so its not natural in flow.